# What are cookies for in a Torrent client (qBittorrent, specifically)?

Tags: bittorrent, cookies, qbittorrent

I noticed that qBittorrent has in "Tools" a "Manage cookies..." section. In it, one finds the cookies stored.

My questions are:

1. What are these cookies for?
2. Who stored them there (that is, how and why were they created)?
3. Can I delete them or will I lose some sort of bittorrent traffic/functionality?
4. Do these cookies pose any kind of privacy threat?

Thanks!

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I already read the [FAQ](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#My_favorite_RSS_feed_requires_cookies_how_can_I_configure_qBittorrent_to_use_them), but, contrary to what it says, I never set any cookies (and even though I delete them, they keep reappering), nor have I ever used or enabled in the settings the RSS feed. I do think the cookies come from the trackers (one comes from FOSSHub, due to qBittorrent, I presume), but there are others like `.google.com` that I cannot imagine where they come from.

*Is it possible to ban/disable the cookies functionality all together?*

EDIT2: Is it possible that I'm suffering from a browser vulnerability that installs cookies when I click on certain links, as if they were magnet links?

Comment: I believe that they are for authenticated trackers. its been a long time since I used one, but you used to have to occasionally browse to a site and login before you could connect to their tracker.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I think you maybe right, since most cookies are from trackers' domains. But where does the `.google.com` cookie come from? I have no torrent with such tracker, I think

Comment: +1 Do you already have an answer for this question?

Comment: @VMMF unfortunately, no. I manually delete them everytime